# Windows batch script for launching an app in a cycle

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to open an app every minute, then close it and wait for 1 second, then repeat the whole process. I tried to write a script, it's opening new cmd window every minute, but doesn't launch the app (when I type "C:\Program Files\App\app.exe" into cmd, it launches fine)

```
:BEGIN
START /I "C:\Program Files\App\app.exe"
TIMEOUT 60
TASKKILL /F /IM "C:\Program Files\App\app.exe"
TIMEOUT 1
GOTO :BEGIN
```

Comment: Well your code clearly doesn't attempt the task, it's opening an exectuable file then trying to  close it after 60 seconds then waiting 10 seconds before looping back.  Anyhow, if you had looked at the help information for the command you are using, you'd have clearly noted that the first doublequoted string is read as the title, _(Open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the enter key)_. You should therefore use `Start "" /I "%ProgramFiles%\App\app.exe"`, _where the first set of doublequotes can stay as an empty title or you can insert your title of choice_.

Comment: I see you've now edited it to wait for one second, _which is still not what you've written in your question body!_ I would also suggest that you check out the usage information for the `taskkill` command too, _because you're using it incorrectly, (`taskkill /?`)_. It should not have the full path, just `TaskKill /F /IM app.exe` would be my suggestion.